# GeoServer does not show sql data store?

Tags: geoserver

I've just installed Geoserver 2.3-RC1 on windows 7 64bit and JRE 6.43 and downloaded the relevant sql extensions and Microsoft files .
As instructed , I've copied "gt-jdbc-sqlserver-9.0-RC1.jar" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.3-RC1\lib" and also the x86 versions of "sqljdbc_auth.dll" and "sqljdbc_xa.dll" to "C:\Windows\System32".

I've restarted geoserver and went to Add Store and still didn't see SQL option.

I've tried doing the same with the x64 versions of the dlls , same result.

What am I missing ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved , Had to put the DLL in this folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.3-RC1\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib

Comment: you mean jar or dlls ?