# Adding sql store to opengeo?

Tags: geoserver, windows-7

I recently downloaded and installed  GeoServer 2.6.2.
One of my other colleagues asked me to add an SQL store for a proof of concept we are doing.

When navigating to the "add new store" page I could not find the SQL store. 
I have followed the instructions in the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/data/database/sqlserver.html), but cannot seem to get it working.

I have tried [GeoServer does not show sql data store?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53947/geoserver-does-not-show-sql-data-), but I still cannot seem to get it configured.

I am new to web mapping.

My system:
 - Win7 Pro.
 - jre-8u40-windows-i586
 - GeoServer 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the versions of the drivers, SQL and geoserver weren't compatible.
So I had to do a bit of reading to find out what drivers were required by my environment. Once that was done, it was a simple matter of following the instructions.